# How find duplicated[s] line[s] and remove it?

Tags: bash, shell, nagios, nrpe

I had to append in my `nrpe.cfg` file this line, in more than 200 servers:

```
command[check_utc]=/company/nrpe/libexec/check_utc.sh
```

But for some issues some machines have more than once this line. So now I would like to check if there's more than once and remove it, leaving just one line with the specified command.
I need to do this in `shell` script.

Comment: They're not adjacents Steven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1: Eliminate all duplicate lines**

```
    cat filename | sort | uniq > outfile
    mv outfile filename
```

The `|` characters feed the output of the commands on the left into the commands on the right as input.

The `cat` command reads the contents of the file to standard output (the screen or another file)

The `sort` command sorts the output alphabetically, which is needed before using `uniq`...

The `uniq` command eliminates adjacent duplicate values

The `> outfile` writes the output of the last step to a file named "outfile"

The `mv` command replaces the original file with the new data file outfile

This method will be destructive because it will remove all duplicate lines of ANY kind, not just the one you want to remove.

**Method 2: Remove all instances of the specific line, then re-add once**

```
    cat filename | sed 's/command\[check_utc\]\=\/company\/nrpe\/libexec\/check_utc.sh//' > outfile
    mv outfile filename
```

The `sed` command allows string substitutions to be performed on specific string patterns. the format for such a command is `sed 's/find/replace/'` to find the first instance of 'find' on each line and replace it with 'replace'. To make it work on every instance on each line you add 'g' to the end, i.e. `sed 's/find/replace/g'`

The `\` characters cause `sed` to literally interpret special characters in the string that would otherwise be misread as special instructions.

The command above will completely remove all instances of that specific string (replacing it with nothing), which you will then need to follow with editing the code and adding it back in once

**Method 3: Remove all instances, then re-add automatically to the end of the file**

```
    cat filename | sed 's/command\[check_utc\]\=\/company\/nrpe\/libexec\/check_utc.sh//' > outfile
    mv outfile filename
    echo "command[check_utc]=/company/nrpe/libexec/check_utc.sh" >> filename
```

This is the same code as above, but after removing all instances of the string, you use `echo` to print the line and use `>>` to append the text to the end of the contents of filename

Comment: This file is a configuration file as it's name indicates, `nrpe.cfg`, so that's why the lines are not adjacent and I should keep the file as it's, so any line would be modified, just removed the duplicated line. And append it at the end.
Thank you for your answer!

Comment: F.Y.I. I accidentally included \ in the echo command, these are printed literally by echo and should be excluded. You may want to double check your cfg file to make sure they weren't included in the text.

I have changed to code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If the lines are not adjacent, and you do not mind sorting them, this will work.

```
$ cat foo.txt
wings of fire
this is a test
food that are killing you
this is a test
```

Result

```
$ sort -u foo.txt
food that are killing you
this is a test
wings of fire
```